# Can I rely on CamelSplitComplete when streaming?

Tags: apache-camel

We have a process where we are processing a large file. We are using a splitter and using `streaming()`.

The [docs](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) say

> **streaming** If enabled then Camel will split in a streaming fashion, which means it will split the input message in chunks. This reduces the memory overhead. For example if you split big messages its recommended to enable streaming. If streaming is enabled then the sub-message replies will be aggregated out-of-order, eg in the order they come back. If disabled, Camel will process sub-message replies in the same order as they where splitted.

So I know that exchanges can be aggregated out of order. So does the splitter mark the last exchange it handles with the CamelSplitComplete set to true? If so, then it could get aggregated out of order and I'll end up considering my aggregation complete before I've aggregated all messages. This would lead to missing data.

If instead it marks the exchange CamelSplitComplete only when it knows it's the last one to be aggregated, then I believe I can rely on it.

UPDATE:
Assuming that it is safe to rely on CamelSplitComplete in the case above, is it safe to rely on it if my routes do filtering? I assume not, because the last row might match the filter criteria and be removed.

Comment: you should not relay on CamelSplitComplete when you are using filters.

Comment: @sagar thanks, yeah, that's what we learned the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

I have done split of large files with streaming and I have used the CamelSplitComplete property to do some processing after split is done. So yes, you can rely on it to be the last exchange. Off course, it is best to have a Camel unit test to verify test. But it worked for me. I can't say about filter, since what if you filtered out the last exchange?

Comment: Yeah, I need to just add some logging on small files and see what's going on.

Comment: I tried to check for CamelSplitComplete after the filter and because the message didn't reach the check, nothing happens although the split has finished.